# Does EOS have builtin pegged asset like bitshares does?

Tags: asset

In bitshares there are builtin support for pegged asset, like bitUSD, bitCNY etc, does EOS have any of such mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it should be fairly easy to implement as a smart contract, especially given bancor will be running on the platform as well.

https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/eosio-blockchain-to-implement-the-bancor-protocol-300602995.html

Comment: Ok, one problem I think is many users take the pegged fiat currency as a base currency, if it is issued by arbitrary users/party, then it does not have the credit as in bitshares for it's issued by the platform itself.

Comment: This is something block.one could add later.  If users are trusting the software block.one has written then there isn't any reason they wouldn't trust a block.one smart contract with pegged assets.  I know nothing about bitshares, but it was my understanding you're still trusting some kind of "exit node" to honor the fiat peg when looking to exit the system when discussing with friends.  Also, Ethereum doesn't provide a pegged fiat currency out of the box, and users don't have a problem with that, I don't see why they would have a problem using EOS rather than a fiat currency.